# Question on Tom Apostol's Proof for Method of Exhaustion

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, inequality, proof-explanation

Currently, I am going through Tom Apostol's "Calculus: Volume 1 Second Edition" as I heard this was a good book to get a solid understanding of calculus and I wasn't satisfied with James Stewart's 9th edition calculus book.

I am on page 6 of the book and I am having some trouble. On pages 5 and 6, Apostol is proving that the area under the curve of $y = x^2$ between $x = 0$ and $x = b$ is equal to $\frac{b^3}3$, or $\frac{1}3$ of a rectangle with a base of length $b$ and a height of $b^2$. After proving that $1^2 + 2^2 +...+(n-1)^2 = $ $\frac{n^3}3 +$  $\frac{n^2}2 + $ $\frac{n}6$ (although I didn't fully understand how Apostol proved that either, this video by blackpenredpen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpA7oNmHobM&ab_channel=blackpenredpen cleared that up for me so if anyone has trouble with that, check the link out), Apostol goes on to say:

**For our purposes, we do not need the exact expressions given in the right-hand members of (I.3) and (I.4), or they can be proved directly by induction. (A proof by induction is given in Section I 4.1.)**

**All we need are the two inequalities**

**$1^2 + 2^2 + ... +   (n-1)^2$ < $\frac{n^3}3$ < $1^2 +    2^2 + ... + n^2$**

**which are valid for every integer n $\geq$ 1. These inequalities can be deduced easily as consequences of (I.3) and (I.4), or they can be proved by induction. (A proof by induction is given in Section I 4.1.)**

**If we multiply both inequalities in (I.5.) by $\frac{b^3}{n^3}$ and make use of (I.1) and (I.2), we obtain**

$s_n$ < $\frac{b^3}3$ < $S_n$

**for every n. The inequalities in (1.6) tell us that $\frac{b^3}3$ is a number which lies between $s_n$ and $S_n$ for every n. We will now prove that $\frac{b^3}3$ is the only number which has this property. In other words, we assert that if A is any number which satisfies the inequalities**

$s_n$ < A < $S_n$

**for every positive integer n, then A = $\frac{b^3}3$. It is because of this fact that Archimedes concluded that the area of the parabolic segment is $\frac{b^3}3$.**

My questions arises at the inequality: **$1^2 + 2^2 + ... +   (n-1)^2$ < $\frac{n^3}3$ < $1^2 +    2^2 + ... + n^2$**

I understand that the values less than $\frac{n^3}3$ are the sum of squares of the heights of rectangles under the parabolic segment where $y=x^2$ and the values greater than $\frac{n^3}3$ are the sum of squares of the heights of rectangles that extend beyond the parabolic segment where $y=x^2$.

My question is, how did Apostol come up with the idea to use $\frac{n^3}3$ in the inequality?

I have looked to this link [Method of Exhaustion applied to Parabolic Segment in Apostol's Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265765/method-of-exhaustion-applied-to-parabolic-segment-in-apostols-calculus) before I asked this question as this was the closest I found to someone asking a similar question but I could not find the answer.

For context, I have provided images of pages 1 through 8 so I can show you all that Apostol is doing for this proof.

Also, sorry for any formatting errors as this is my first time posting on this site.

Images:

[Pages 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBVhh.png)

[Pages 3 and 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4WLi.jpg)

[Pages 5 and 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPHYt.png)

[Pages 7 and 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB6F2.jpg)

Comment: Well, he knows what the answer is.

Comment: "how did Apostol come up with the idea to use $\frac{n^3}3$ in the inequality?" I strongly suspect that he didn't originate the idea.  Calculus probably evolved through centuries of blind research down mostly dead-end allies.  Over the centuries, at or before the development of Calculus in the 1600's on, some mathematician came up with the idea.  The situation was **perhaps** a hybrid of idea born of talent combined with intellectually winning the lotto.

Comment: @user2661923 So should I just move on and not worry about it? I mean, I can prove it with limits like this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006273/help-with-apostols-calculus-regarding-method-of-exhaustion) did but I cannot in the fashion that Apostol did.

Comment: "So should I just move on and not worry about it?"  Unclear what you are asking.  If you are asking whether you need to verify that his analysis is valid, then **yes**, you do.  Alternatively, if you are worrying that your intuition has not stretched to the point where you might have had a chance to originate the analysis, then **no** you don't need to worry about it.  However, intuition stretching is very important.  So it is a good idea (besides the formal verification) to intuitively grasp his idea(s).

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your quick reply. By moving on from it, I meant that I would just keep progressing with the book if that is what I should do. I can understand how found the area of the parabolic segment of y=x^2 between x = 0 and x = b through limits but in Apostol's version of the proof, he does not use limits. To me, he pulled the n^3/3 from somewhere and I do not know where. Apologies if my math symbols aren't correctly formatted.

Comment: I disagree; Apostol is (very informally) using the 
[squeeze theorem of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).
His central idea is that if $f(n) = \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, then 
$f(n-1) < \frac{n^3}{3} < f(n).$  The right side of the inequality is immediate.
For the left side, simply note that $(n-1)n(2n-1) = 2n^3 - 3n^2 + n.$  I recommend
that you reread that section.

Comment: @user2661923 Yeah, so if we take the limit of f(n-1) where n approaches infinity, the value we are approaching is b^3/3. If we take the limit of f(n) where n approaches infinity, again the value we are approaching is b^3/3. Hence, we can conclude the area under the parabola of y=x^2 between x = 0 and x= b is b^3/3. Maybe I am not understanding you and apologies if I am not but I am still confused as to where n^3/3 came from. As you suggested previously, the idea may have come from a previous development of calculus that occurred long before Apostol did this proof.

Comment: See my answer.  If more questions, post the question immediately following my answer, and I will be automatically flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early 1700's, Bernoulli proved (without Calculus) that for any positive integer $k$, there exists a unique set of rational numbers $c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_k$ such that

for any positive integer $n$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k = c_0n^{(k+1)} + c_1n^k + \cdots + c_kn^1.$$

Actually, Bernoulli took it one step further, and originated the idea of Bernoulli numbers.  For the purposes of this discussion, that is **irrelevant**.

Bernoulli's demonstration is (**partially**) recreated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697950/general-form-for-sum-of-powers/2698204?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C14.8039#2698204).

So, it was well known, for centuries that

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n i^3 = \frac{1}{3}n^3 + \frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{6}n.$$

What Apostol is doing in these first few pages is giving you an informal (but valid) glimpse of estimating the area under the curve through a series of step functions (e.g. rectangles).  His algebra in the pages that you cited is **valid**.

**Whoever** originated the idea that Apostol is merely repeating had the vision that the area of the *inner* rectangles would always be less than $\frac{b^2}{3}$ but would get closer and closer to $\frac{b^2}{3}.$

The analyis is that the $k$-th rectangle has width $\frac{b}{n}$ and height $\left(\frac{kb}{n}\right)^2.$  Therefore, the $k$-th rectangle has area $\frac{b^3}{n^3}k^2.$

Therefore, the sum of the area of the inner rectangles is

$$\frac{b^3}{n^3} \times \sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)}k^2$$

and the sum of the area of the outer rectangles is

$$\frac{b^3}{n^3} \times \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2.$$

From the above algebra, it is immediate that as $n \to \infty$, the sum of the area of the inner triangles will converge to $\frac{b^3}{3}$ **from below**, and the sum of the area of the outer triangles will converge to $\frac{b^3}{3}$ **from above**.

Therefore, Apostol is (through the informal use of the squeeze theorem of limits) repeating the idea that *some Calculus pioneer* envisioned: the **exact** area under the curve has to be $\frac{b^3}{3}.$

What may be confusing is that Apostol's (**algebra-only, no Calculus**) derivation of the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3$, on page 6, though valid, is somewhat non-standard.  The non-Calculus derivation normally uses induction, as in the mathSE link that I cited.

Comment: Thank you! In addition to your response, I was able to clear up all other questions about this proof with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbNbYH85lZ4) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvANCW-WDqk). I understand now why the n^3/3 was used. Thank you!